# select an array of elements and use them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using this syntax:

```
var position = array($('#ipadmenu > section').attr('data-order'));
```

I cannot get my code to work. I have never used arrays before so im kind of lost on how to use them. (especially in jquery).

How would I make an array of all section elements and associate the value of data-order to that list. Example:

```
first section - data-order:1
second section - data-order:2
```

etc and then use that info afterwards.

Thank you!

Comment: `$('#ipadmenu > section').attr('data-order')` will already return an object you could parse with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or slice with [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: `array` has no special meaning in JavaScript.

Comment: so var position = $('#ipadmenu > section').attr('data-order').each; would return the right array?

Comment: @jbyrd: That is incorrect. `attr('data-order')` will only return the value of the attribute for the first selected element, not an array.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Doh! Yes, of course, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.attr` just gets *one* attribute -- [the first one found by the jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) -- you need to build your array element by element. One way to do that is `.each` (you can also use `.data` to extract data attributes):

```
var position = new Array;
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function() {
    position.push($(this).data('order'));
});

alert(position[0]);  // alerts "1"
```

This will be an indexed array, not an associative array. To build one of those (which in JavaScript is technically an object, not any kind of array) just change the inner part of your `.each` loop:

```
var position = {};
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function(i) {
    position["section"+i] = $(this).data('order');
});
```

The resulting object `position` can now be accessed like:

```
alert(position['section1']); // alerts "1"
```

A different approach involves using [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), but since that only works on arrays, not jQuery objects, you need to use `jQuery.makeArray` to convert your selection into a true array first:

```
var position = $.map($.makeArray($('#ipadmenu > section')), function() {
    return $(this).data('order');
} );  // position is now an indexed array
```

This approach is technically shorter than using `.each`, but I find it less clear.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var orders = [];
$('#ipadmenu > section').each(function() {
    orders.push($(this).data('order'))
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ipadmenu">
    <section data-order="1">1</section>
    <section data-order="2">2</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do something like this:

```
// Get the elements and put them in an array
var position = $('#ipadmenu section').toArray();
console.log(position);

// Loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++){
  // Display the attribute value for each one
  console.log("Section " + i + ": " + $(position[i]).attr('data-order'));
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/U6n8E/3/